# String vibration $\rightarrow$ particle properties

Tags: particle-physics, string-theory, normal-modes, calabi-yau

The vibrating of the strings is identified with some properties attributable to the particles.
How can I find the equations that show how the mode of vibration of a string (in the Calabi-Yau manifolds) can be traced back to the properties of a particle?

Comment: maybe this write up will help?http://www.maths.liv.ac.uk/TheorPhys/people/staff/faraggi/teaching/student_thesis/SeanTurner.pdf

Comment: Possibly related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22559

Comment: Thank you very much both suggestions