# Is there a clean mathematical way to deduce grand unification from string theory?

Tags: particle-physics, string-theory, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

The question says it all. Simply stated:

Can one *prove* grand unification from string theory?
What is the argument chain of such a proof?

The textbooks I read so far only appear to give hand-waving
arguments.

The question is not about deducing the standard model. The question is about deducing grand unification. This means that there is a single large Lie group.

Can one *prove* somehow that string theory produces a unique (large) Lie group?

Comment: Of course not. No proof, not even an aspirational trail.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22559).

Answer (score 1):

It's straightforward to implement grand unification in string theory, but it's [not required](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0610104).